# How to realize the function $\bar f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x,\theta)\;d\theta$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Maybe this sounds quite silly and maybe I should take a break from math during Christmas and I apologize in advance, but how should I realize this function:

$$\bar f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x,\theta)\;d\theta$$

In principle, this seems as an average value to me but average value over an angular interval (if such a term exists)? What is the role of $x$? Is this function somehow independent of radius?

Any help will be much appreciated! Many thanks and happy holidays!

Comment: Yes - I call this the circular mean value theorem.

Comment: @SeanRoberson what about $x$ though? If it a MVT sort of thing, then should $x \in [0,2\pi]$? But why it appears also inside the integral?